# Can't exitThread with waitForMultipleObjects

Tags: c, windows, multithreading, waitformultipleobjects

I have 2 threads, the first is doing:`

```
while(1){

    if(recv(conn_s, (char*) &i, sizeof(i),0)>0){

        if(i==28){
            SetEvent(event);
            //printf("nell if di 28\n");
            HANDLE t;
            sleep(1);
            //TerminateThread(scegli, 0);
            //if (CloseHandle(scegli)==0) printf("error close\n");
            t=CreateThread(NULL, 0, (LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE) avvia_conversazioneCl, conn, SYNCHRONIZE, 0);
            WaitForSingleObject(t, INFINITE);
```

the second one:

```
       const HANDLE handles[2]={event, stdinHandle};

       while(1){

            switch(WaitForMultipleObjects(num, handles, FALSE, 0)){
                case 0: 

                        ExitThread(-1);
                        break;

                case 1:
                                    r=ReadConsole(stdinHandle, &interlocutore, nLength, &charsRead, NULL);
                                    if (r==0){
                                        printf("%d\n", GetLastError());
                                    }
                                    //global_value_to_exit=1;
                                    int size=strlen(interlocutore);
                                     interlocutore[size-2]='\0';

                                    int verifica=verifica_interlocutore(interlocutore); 
                                     if (verifica==0){
                                         printf("interlocutore non disponibile, riprova: \n");
                                         continue;
                                    }



                                    int rrr=send(socket, interlocutore, size, 0);
                                    if (rrr<=0){
                                        printf("send error\n");
                                    }
                                    sleep(1);
                                    if(recv(socket, (char*) &ack, sizeof(int), 0)==SOCKET_ERROR){
                                        printf("errore: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
                                    }
                                    printf("ho ricevuto %d\n", (int) ack);
                                    if(ack==999){

                                        //sleep(1);
                                         HANDLE t;
                                        DWORD tID;
                                        t=CreateThread(NULL, 0, (LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE) avvia_conversazioneCl, conn_s, 0, &tID);
                                        WaitForSingleObject(t, INFINITE);
                                        CloseHandle(t);
                                        //global_value_to_exit=0;
                                        ack=0;
                                        vis=CreateThread(NULL, 0, (LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE) visualizza_utenti, conn_s, 0, &visID);
                                     }
                                     //ResetEvent(stdinHandle);
                                     break;

                case WAIT_FAILED: 
                                perror("failed: \n");

                                break;
    }

    memset(interlocutore, 0, sizeof(interlocutore));
}

    return NULL;

}
```

also:

```
  const HANDLE handles[2]={event, stdinHandle};

   event=CreateEvent(NULL, FALSE, FALSE, NULL);

   stdinHandle=GetStdHandle(STD_INPUT_HANDLE);`
```

**The point is**:
if i write something in console i do things with the second thread, if i get 28 with the receive i would like to make the second thread exit so i  sett to signaled event. at this point with the waitformultipleobjects i should get into case 0 and exit the thread. instead after i've already recv 28 and changed the status of event, if i write something in console the second thread enters case 1.
after writing something else it seems to be dead

any advice?

Comment: Why do you think it should enter case 0? What do you expect WaitForMultipleObjects to return when the event is signaled? Did you read the documentation?

Comment: (Actually, since WAIT_OBJECT_0 happens to have the value 0, it should enter case 0. But nowhere in the documentation does it say that WAIT_OBJECT_0 has the value 0)

Comment: Is the second thread waiting on the same event that the first thread is setting?

Comment: The second thread is waiting on 2handles, the first is event (signaled by the first when in if i==28), the other is the console handle.

Comment: Te retuen value should be 0+index of the signaled handle in the array

Comment: The code in case 1 doesn't look like it will necessarily finish promptly.  It both waits for console input and sends and receives from a socket.  If that code is still running, setting the event won't do anything.  You need to use a debugger to see what's going on.